# How can I fix 'str' object has no attribute 'append' (AttributeError)?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, attributeerror

I have the following for loop:

```
for x in list:
    while i in range(0, len(list)):
        exec('list_entry'+str(i).append(x))
        i+=1
```

Problem: I want to fill my already existing empty lists (named `list_entry_1`, `list_entry_2`, etc.) with entries of another `list`. For each entry in the list, there exists already an associated empty list. However, the empty lists are not filled because they are recognised as strings and not as lists by the loop (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'). How can I fix this error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't use dynamic variable names in the first place, use a dictionary or list.

Comment: No, no, no - this is not how you deal with multiple lists, you put them in a list themselves and use an ordinary `for` loop to process them.

Comment: And don't use a `while` loop, use `for i in range(len(list)):`

Comment: @jasonharper ...or have we been going about it all wrong? We should be wrapping all of our code in exec('''...''')!

Comment: or `for idx, _ in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Perhaps I can briefly explain what I am trying to do. I have a list (or a dictionary) that contains tensors in the form of matrices. I want to subtract each entry of one matrix with the corresponding entry of the following matrix and write the result into a new file. Unfortunately, I am quite new to python and therefore have less experience with this programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have `exec(f'list_entry{i}.append({x})')`, but that is definitely a weird way of going about it.

The issue is that you were combining a string-to-be-executed with straight code. Mix max mish mash

Comment: When I do this, I got an NameError that the name 'list_entry' is not defined.

Comment: @Alice I forgot the second underscore in the name.
`exec(f'list_entry_{i}.append({x})')`